# How to insert value at specific column in text files

Tags: c#

I have 3 txt files which are generated on a daily basis by one of our systems, that need values inserted at specific column positions.

I've accomplished this with the code below, however:

1. The specific value (**LineText) needs to be on all rows that have text and not just one row. I am not sure how to accomplish this.
2. My code currently inserts the value (**LineText), however it pushes everything over. Is there a way for the value to be inserted without pushing the rest of the data over?
3. Each day 3 files will be generated with the names REYYYYMMDD.TXT, TRYYYYMMDD.TXT and CTYYYYMMDD.TXT. Is there a way for the code to pick up these names? I've tried using wildcards such as RE*.TXT, TR*.TXT etc but it doesn't work.

Results example below (What my code currently does with the **`RE20150109.TXT`** file)

```
223016254     CSST45124                      
167520001   EUR  SKBSUS12454                    
158013456     CSST15568                      
140490002     CSST14779                      
167520004     SKBSUS88897                    
515800001     CSST13679                      
149370003     CSST32897                      
161930009     RTVS10035
```

Below is what I would like it to do but am not sure how :

```
223016254  EUR  CSST45124                      
167520001  EUR  SKBSUS12454                    
158013456  EUR  CSST15568                      
140490002  EUR  CSST14779                      
167520004  EUR  SKBSUS88897                    
515800001  EUR  CSST13679                      
149370003  EUR  CSST32897                      
161930009  EUR  RTVS10035
```

My C# code is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AstTXTEdit
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string REFilePath = @"C:\AstImport\RE20150109.TXT";
        int RElineNo = 1; //How do i set this to be all rows within the text file?
        string RELineText = "";
        int REPosition = 12;

        var REFullContent = File.ReadAllLines(REFilePath);
        RELineText = REFullContent[RElineNo];
        RELineText = RELineText.Insert(REPosition, "EUR");
        REFullContent[RElineNo] = RELineText;
        File.WriteAllLines(REFilePath, REFullContent);

        string TRFilePath = @"C:\AstImport\TR20150109.TXT";
        int TRlineNo = 1; //How do i set this to be all rows within the text file?
        string TRLineText = "";
        int TRPosition = 40;

        var FullContent = File.ReadAllLines(TRFilePath);
        TRLineText = FullContent[TRlineNo];
        TRLineText = TRLineText.Insert(TRPosition, "Y");
        FullContent[TRlineNo] = TRLineText;
        File.WriteAllLines(TRFilePath, FullContent);

        string CTFilePath = @"C:\AstImport\CT20150109.TXT";
        int CTlineNo = 1; //How do i set this to be all rows within the text file?
        string CTLineText = "";
        int CTPosition = 36;

        var CTFullContent = File.ReadAllLines(CTFilePath);
        CTLineText = FullContent[CTlineNo];
        CTLineText = CTLineText.Insert(CTPosition, "I");
        FullContent[CTlineNo] = CTLineText;
        File.WriteAllLines(CTFilePath, FullContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Assistance would be most appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Andrea

Comment: Not an answer but a tip: you're doing the same thing three times. In that case: don't copy-paste your code, but extract it into a method and call that with the relevant parameters.

Comment: @BCdotNET Do you have an example of what you mean? I am still very new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two questions:

> The specific value (**LineText) needs to be on all rows that have text and not just one row. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

and

> My code currently inserts the value (**LineText), however it pushes everything over. Is there a way for the value to be inserted without pushing the rest of the data over?

can be solved by iterating all lines with the `Select` and transforming each line by first inserting the new string an then removing the same length of characters after the insertion:

```
// Read entire file;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("data2.txt");
var eur = "EUR"; // String to insert.
// Calc the position to insert at.
var insertAt = "223016254".Length + 1; 
var result = 
    lines
    .Select(x => 
        // Insert the 'eur' string.
        x.Insert(insertAt, eur)
        // Remove the spaces after insertion.
        .Remove(insertAt + eur.Length, eur.Length))
    .ToList();
```

As far as the third question is concerned:

> Each day 3 files will be generated with the names REYYYYMMDD.TXT, TRYYYYMMDD.TXT and CTYYYYMMDD.TXT. Is there a way for the code to pick up these names?

I wouldn't use `Directory.GetFiles` wildcards because in most cases they are too simple. A linq query with with a regex file name pattern could do much more:

```
string fileNamePattern = @"(CT|RE|TR)\d{8}\.TXT$"
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
files = 
    files
    .Where(fileName => 
        Regex.IsMatch(fileName, fileNamePattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I've update the answer and added a non-stream example for inserting the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Question 3:

```
    List<string> fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\AstImport", "RE*.TXT").ToList();
    fileNames.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myfolder", "TR*.TXT"));

    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: It would be easy to insert the missing strings with linq

```
var v = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(s => { string[] arr = s.Split(' '); if (arr[1] == "EUR") return s; else return String.Join(" ", new string[] { arr[0], "EUR", arr[1] }); });
File.WriteAllLines(path, v);
```

Question 2: I did not understand the question

Question 3: The Linq Answer

```
Directory.GetFiles("path", "RE*.txt").ToList().ForEach(s => { /* Same as 1 */ });
```